# Override internal symbol in different modules in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, uiimage, nsbundle

I have a project comprising multiple frameworks, a couple of which need to initialize `UIImage` instances. `UIImage`'s initializer defaults to using `Bundle.main` if you don't specify a Bundle.

This means if the image asset I am trying access is in the current (non-main) bundle, then I need to specify the bundle or it will return `nil` from `UIImage(named: "MyImage")`.

I am trying to work around this with a clean implementation like so:

```
fileprivate class _Foo { }
extension Bundle {
  static var current: Bundle { .init(for: Foo.self) }
}    

public extension UIImage {    
  static func inCurrentBundle(named name: String) -> UIImage? {
    return UIImage(named: name, in: .current, compatibleWith: nil)
  }
}
```

The `Bundle` extension above is by default `internal` to the module it is defined in, so my idea was to define a new `extension Bundle` with a `Bundle.current` in each module. However, this obviously doesn't work because the `.current` symbol in the `inCurrentBundle` method uses the implementation above it and doesn't get "overridden" by another one even if `inCurrentBundle` is called from a different module.

Can anyone think of a way to tweak this so the approach works without having to specify a bundle?

Note: while I can certainly think of various workarounds, I am specifically trying to come up with an elegant solution which is simple and minimal. I am particularly interested in whether there's any way to provide some skeleton that can be overridden between modules.